# problem with loop in shell

Tags: unix, shell

I have a problem with loop , I used while in my script as below :

```
while read LINE 
do {
}
done
```

but the problem is each time I should press enter while running the script, and it supposed to do this 50000 time ! 
how could I change this to a loop that runs automatically ?

could I count the length of my file using : lenght=`wc -l < myfile 
and then use it ? or any better solution ?

Comment: If you want to read lines from a file, then why are you trying to read from the console?

Comment: As a general rule of thumb you will get the best answer if you explain what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: so, questions is how i must enter 50000 lines without enters?

Comment: As @KyleBrandt said: what are you actually trying to do in a while loop?

Comment: I work on a log file and it has 50000 rows , I wrote commands in while loop , but it needs enter for each row and it's impossible !

Answer (score 1):

You can use a for loop?

```
for i in {1..5}
  do
  echo "I have $i bottle(s) of Mountain Dew"
done

I have 1 bottle(s) of Mountain Dew
I have 2 bottle(s) of Mountain Dew
I have 3 bottle(s) of Mountain Dew
I have 4 bottle(s) of Mountain Dew
I have 5 bottle(s) of Mountain Dew
```

You can even loop backwards!

```
for i in {5..1}
  do
  echo "I have $i bottle(s) of Mountain Dew"
done

I have 5 bottle(s) of Mountain Dew
I have 4 bottle(s) of Mountain Dew
I have 3 bottle(s) of Mountain Dew
I have 2 bottle(s) of Mountain Dew
I have 1 bottle(s) of Mountain Dew
```

Answer (score 0):

your_script < 5000_lines.dat

In your while you should check for "not EoF" and put the `read` into the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
yes "" | while ....
```

That sends a stream of newlines that your while-body can use.